# Jade checkbox checked attribute unchecked based on conditional (if)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

How do I get jade to render the checked attribute of a checkbox based on a conditional?
Like these two versions of the HTML checkbox tag:

This seems to be the ONLY valid version of unchecked:

> ```
> >  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
> ```

While this is checked:

> ```
> > <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked">
> ```

Here is what I've tried so far:

This Jade is fine:

```
    input(type="checkbox", name="completed", checked=(true===true ? "checked" : "")).checkbox
```

because it renders this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="completed" checked="checked" class="checkbox">
```

but this Jade is not fine:

```
    input(type="checkbox", name="completed", checked=(false===true ? "checked" : "")).checkbox
```

because it renders this:

> `<input type="checkbox" name="completed" checked="" class="checkbox">`

instead of this:

> `<input type="checkbox" name="completed" class="checkbox">`

How do I get Jade to render the entire checked attribute instead of just the value of the checked attibute?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="completed", checked=(true===false ? "checked" : undefined))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 18):

No need to specify the values:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="completed", checked=(condition))
```

If condition is false, there is no checked attribute will added.

Comment: No, if condition is false, null or undefined then "checked" will ignored

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing is by 'if' condition:

```
if(#{data.refrigerated} == '1')
   input(type='checkbox', name='refrigerated', checked)
else
   input(type='checkbox', name='refrigerated')
```

When condition will be true, You will get checked checkbox on DOM otherwise you will get unchecked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
  option(value='man' selected = profile.sex ==='man') man
  option(value='female' selected = profile.sex ==='female') female
```