# Set checked attribute of checkbox in Jade template based on input from Node

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to set a checkbox's 'checked' attribute based whether the category id exists in an articles category array.

each category in the categories object has the fields '_id' and 'name', example:
{
   _id: 12, name: Preparations
}

articles.categories is an array of id's, example: [1, 12, 22]

This is what I have now:

```
- categories.forEach(function(category) {
        - var check = 'false'
        - article.categories.forEach(function(id) {
            - if(id === category._id) {
                - check = 'true'
            - }
        - });

        - if(check == 'true') {
            li: label.checkbox
                input(type="checkbox", name="categories", checked, value=category._id)
                =category.name
        - } else {
            li: label.checkbox
                input(type="checkbox", name="categories", value=category._id)
                =category.name
        - }     
- });
```

The data being passed in is correct and it is iterating through the correct values, I just need to be able to set the checked attribute based on a match. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jade checkbox checked attribute unchecked based on conditional (if)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147772/jade-checkbox-checked-attribute-unchecked-based-on-conditional-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this few days ago. What I did is assign a boolean value to the 'checked' attribute. See code below. Note that I changed your check variable from string to boolean. I also removed the if-then-else statement.

```
- categories.forEach(function(category) {
    - var check = false
    - article.categories.forEach(function(id) {
        - if(id === category._id) {
            - check = true
        - }
    - });

    li: label.checkbox
        input(type="checkbox", name="categories", checked=check, value=category._id)
        =category.name     
- });
```

Comment: Thanks Third Santor, I originally had check as a boolean but couldn't get it to work. Using your suggestions above check is never set to true on any my test cases. I don't see what is wrong with the comparison though.

Comment: Ok so printing id and category._id side by side I can see that even when they match the if statement is evaluating to false...

Comment: Ok clearly the comparison fails (even with non type-specific '==' comparitor) comparing individually to strings works, but for some reason they refuse to evaluate to true

Comment: using toString() solved the issue... I'm not clever enough to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use indexOf (at least since node > 0.5.1)

`input(type="checkbox", name="categories", checked=article.categories.indexOf(category._id) !=-1)`