# return a checkbox value in jade. using node.js ,express and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, checkbox

I saved the checkbox value in mongoDB. passed the value to the page by

```
if (req.session.user.Single === undefined) {single_status= 'false'} else {single_status= ''};

res.render('user-profile', { 
    Single: single_status,
)};
```

Then i have this in jade

```
.col-md-4
 label-option(for="checkbox")
 input(type="checkbox", checked="#{Single}", name='single', id='single')
```

on the rendered view. It appears checked="false" so it is always checked. 
how to a return the valve to the checkbox to present the existing checked / unchecked?

```
<label-option for="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" checked="false" name="single" id="single"> Single Status
</label-option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox HTML element only cares whether you mention the `checked` attribute or not. So, when you say `checked="false"` is  the same as saying `checked` or `checked="true"`.

If you want to uncheck the input element, you have to completely omit the `checked` attribute.

Example:

`input(type ='radio', name='status', checked)`

**One way to do this dynamically** is this one *([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147772/jade-checkbox-checked-attribute-unchecked-based-on-conditional-if))*:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="status", checked=(true===false ? "checked" : undefined))
```

Doing it like this means that the `checked` attribute will be rendered if the expression is true; if the expression is false, it will simply omit it.